# Android notification does not go though firebase function

Tags: android, android-notifications

I had some problem with the firebase notification that does not go through the function while the app is in background while debug. It show different notification style which was not the design i wanted.

I had tried to trace the notification function triggered but i had no clue on it. What i know was when i changed the app icon in android manifi the notification icon will changed also. Please help me.

I want to combine the notification together to make it tidy. Below is my firebase notification code.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
        Notification.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new Notification.InboxStyle();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle() == null){
            // doing something
        }else if(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle().equals("Notification1")){
            // doing something
        }else if(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle().equals("Notification2")){
             // doing something
        }else{
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("MyNotification");
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon);
            inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Enter Content Text");
            inboxStyle.addLine("hi events "+value);
            builder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Use getdata() instead of getNotification() and pass data fields to fcm. Watch this and implement it your way https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKwCgabRV2A&ab_channel=PRABEESHRK

Comment: hi thanks for reply and your advise but i don't think it works because it does not go through this function while app in background. While the apps is open it can run through the function. I will try your advise first.

Comment: what are you sending in the notification payload?

Comment: hi thanks for your reply i think i just found the answer about while the apps in background the notification will create automatically, to customize the notification i must use FCM API add the "Tag" while sending from server. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: @diegoveloper is that for ios ? because i found in FCM API for ios it does not have a "TAG" for grouping notification